# I try to run my python program but when i run it nothing happens

Tags: python

Im having problem running my little interactive story i wrote in python. I keep running into some sort of NON-ASCII error or some sort that doesnt let me run the program.

Heres the program if you want to try it: [Program][1]
Here's my code:

```
#Programmer: 11/8/12
# Story of Doors
# Interactive story where the user can choose between options in between the - - marks.

def main():

    print "I welcome you to the mind of the chosen. A place only understood by those who never forfeit. The chance to walk through the halls is given only but once the time has come for you to decide, will you stand aside, or never regret to have tried?"

#Quest is the word used to decide whether the player wants to play or quit.
    Quest = raw_input("  I welcome you to the mind of the chosen. A place only understood by those who never forfeit. The chance to walk through the halls is given only but once the time has come for you to decide, will you stand aside, or never regret to have tried?")

    if(Quest == "stand aside"):
        print "Have fun asleep, for those who will awake are the ones who take the leap." 
    if (Quest == "never regret to have tried"):
        print "I see you think yourself as worthy, I hope you know, this quest is full of low beings"
    print "Down the hall you walked with a line of doors not covered or locked. The choices are at hand with many experiences to be had."
    print "Step into a door and never look back, for your decisions will open a crack. Your choices are at hand, choose from the list written in sand."

#here the reader\player decides what quest he wants to go on, or what door they want to open. 
    Opendoor = raw_input("Door 1: The door of no troubles where you see everything in doubles ") + ("Door 2: ")  
    if(Opendoor == "Door 1"):

        print "The incense infilled maple shaped door was entered to the begin the scene." 
    print "Going straight through to a land engulfed by the waves controlled, where the shore is seen when the machines flee."
    print "Out through a mix of purple and green lies The Beheaded Dragon who whispers and schemes. 'Come to my lab, and enjoy the lick of a colorful tab.'"
    print "After a flash of happy and sad, you see through perspectives and forget the word 'bad'."
    print "With witches and crafts, comes the great Sage whose be riddled with mad."
    print " I know of a place where the sky is purple and nobodies hurtful heaven at night is spoken of. The minds are torn up with a thought of what’s next."


    ComeAlong = raw_input(" Will you -join the quest- or -eschew the test-? ")
    if(ComeAlong == "eschew test"):
       print "'I accept your decline and reply with a good-bye.'"
    if(ComeAlong == "join quest"):
        print "'I'm glad you see yourself as worthy, just remember kid, in here. No mind is sturdy.'"
        print " Here begins a trip to the land of nomads where you witness a dance and give it a try, for you have no doubts as you see with one eye. Forgotten stories of the times of war, for the children are busy learning to soar."
        print "you join this man with not but one rule 'never turn back, for there are consequences for trying to hack.'"
        print "'This is a place of glitches and traps, but the end lies open with stitches to map'"
    Woman = raw_input(" You journey onward through the forest and trees but come across some women on their knees their eyes are locked and only you hold the keys. You're given the choice to open the lock and -allow them to see- or leave them locked and -mimick the birds and the bees-.")   
    if(Woman == "mimick the birds and the bees"):
        print "You approach the women and accept their tease. They looks up at you with a smile, and simultaneously screech 'We see your story has ended and can now be marked as 'deceased' and within a blink of an eye you are paralyzed with nothing to drink."
        wait(2)
    print "Nice try, but this saddly proves, you're not ready to fly. and with that I wave to you a sincere and heart felt good-bye!"
    if(Woman == "allow them to see"):
            print " You approach the women and give them the keys, they grabs them and begin to flee but while the flock reaches there caves one of the women stands beside you and opens the lock."
            print " 'I know where your headed and can lend you my boat, it's right around the corner sitting by the dock.'"
            print " As you follow the woman you look up onto the sky and read aloud 'Take a deep breath and watch your step' confused by the words you ask the woman 'Hey, whats that mean?' with no response you look down to her but see nothing but a stream"
            print " 'Hello!?' you scream, but no one is to be seen. All alone you begin to gleam followed by your lungs releasing the steam"
            print " With that the scene darkens and you rise from your sleep, just to realize life, is but a dream."



# Second Door of choices.

    if(Opendoor == "Door 2"):
        print "This is a story of a young wounded boy, who was lost in his mind with one little toy. He sat on the floor waiting for more, but after an hour his feelings went sour."
        print "He rose up on his feet and started to wonder. Through the bright door there were tons of new people to meet."
        print " He made it his duty to connect with these people, even if they were him in a past life or sequel."
        print " After some time came a decision. To speak with -the man in the white-, or -the woman with no sight-"
        if(Decision == "the man in the white"):
            print " 'Hello mister. May i ask you some questions?'"
            print " 'Why yes you may, but i dont have time to give you a lesson.'"
            print " 'They will be quick i promise, What brings you here to the land of nostradamus?'"
            print " ' Well isnt it obvious? Nothing more than the thirst for knowledge!'"
            print " 'Ahh I see, but what do you do if you cant find the answer to the riddle you speak?'"
            print " 'Then I learn a new language and ask it to Nietzsche' "
            print " 'What if its a question with no answer?'"
            print "' Then I forget about philosophy and become a great dancer! But in all seriousness, you musn't forget for every box of questions there is box of answers'"
        if(Decision == "the woman with no sight"):
            print " 'Hello miss, do you have some free time?'"
            print " ' Ofcourse I do, and i'll give you it for a dime' "
            print " 'If I pay it is not free ' "
            print " 'it's a reward, not a fee.'"
            print " ' okay but if i dont enjoy what you have to say will I still have to pay?'"
            print " ' I'm sorry but you pay for the herbs, not the tea.'"
            print " 'I understand the concept, but i'll have to disagree.'"

            main()
```

This is the first time I use StackOverflow so if there is anything else I could do to help you guys help me please let me know.

Comment: The exact test of the error message would be useful.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but your main() should be unintended, or it won't work...

Comment: You might need a `if __name__=="__main__": main()`.

Comment: @louism: Sure, but that's not going to cause him to get a non-ASCII-character error during parsing, it'll just make it exit successfully without doing anything.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the title of the post...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It may not hurt to try the folks at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ too. They can offer a bunch of well-rounded tips to a beginning pythonista such as yourself.

Comment: One last thing: I assume you're doing this to learn Python… but in case your real goal is to write interactive fiction, Python is not necessarily the best language for that. See http://inform7.com (also maybe check out TADS and whatever else the kids are using nowadays, if there are any kids doing IF nowadays); it'll probably impress the hell out of you.

Comment: your  main() is in the wrong place

Comment: @Hooked Questions about non-working code are off topic at codereview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On line 28, you have the character `’`, which is not an ASCII character. You need to replace that character with `'`. That will let the program run without errors. In the future, if you run into similar errors, you can use the following command to `grep` for non-ASCII characters:

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" your_file.py
```

Second, you need to put the call to `main()` within the global scope (i.e. it should not have any indentation before it). Right now, it is nested within a conditional and will not be executed when the Python interpreter reads the main body of the file.

Comment: Smart quotes are no fun.  Don't edit your code in something that allows these to creep in.

Comment: If that solved your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark besides the post :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what version of Python this is, but I'm guessing 2.7 (it's definitely not 3.x).

When I save this as a file and run it in 2.7, I get this:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file ./if.py on line 30, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

This means exactly what it says. In Python 2.7, if you want to type any non-ASCII characters in a string literal—even just things like `é`—you must provide an encoding declaration. Read the URL in the error message to see how to do that.

The alternative is to escape the characters. Instead of typing `"Abré"`, you type `"Abr\xe9"`—or, better, `u"Abr\u00e9"`—and it'll work

Meanwhile, either way, you almost certainly want the strings to be Unicode strings, not 8-bit strings. That means instead of `"Foo"`, you want `u"Foo"` everywhere.

Comment: its python 2.4.4.
i tried putting a u before every opening " but still nothing =\

Comment: @user1884176: If I remember right, 2.4 is when the PEP-263 encoding declarations became optional, but not yet mandatory. I believe it _usually_ tries to interpret the source as Latin-1, instead of just bailing automatically like 2.7… but that isn't actually guaranteed. So you still need to write explicit escapes, or add an encoding declaration, if you want to be safe.

Comment: @user1884176: PS, why are you using such an old version of Python in 2012? Especially if you're a student!